# Ajax JQuery request and reponse from Django Template

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, templates, xmlhttprequest

According to **jro** suggestion I am modifying my question and problem I have.

==**URL**==

```
url('^$','pMass.views.index', name='index')  #Index is the main view with form input type text and submit
                                             #If search value is match then it will render result.html template
```

==**VIEW**==

```
#View will find search value and render result.html template if request is not ajax
#If request is ajax then same view will create new queryset and render to same template page (result.html) 

 def index(request):
    error = False
    cid = request.GET

    if 'cnum' in request.GET:
       cid = request.GET['cnum']

    if not cid:
       error = False
       expcount = Experiment.objects.count()
       allmass = SelectedIon.objects.count()

   if request.is_ajax():
       value = request.GET.get('value')
       if value is None:
           result = SelectedIon.objects.filter(monoiso__iexact=value).select_related()
           template = 'result.html'
           data = {
               'results':result,
           }
           return render_to_response(template, data,           
          context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:

       defmass = 0.000001
       massvalue = float(cid)
       masscon = defmass * massvalue
       highrange = massvalue + masscon
       lowrange = massvalue - masscon

       myquery = SelectedIon.objects.select_related().filter(monoiso__range=(lowrange, highrange))
       querycount = myquery.count()

       return render_to_response('result.html', {'query': cid, 'high':highrange, 'low':lowrange, 'sections':myquery, 'qcount':querycount, })

   return render_to_response('index.html', {'error': error, 'exp': expcount,'mass':allmass,})
```

==**result.html**==

```
# I have divided template into two container: main (left) & container (right)
# Left container is for search match (e.g value/title) with hyperlink
# Right container is for detail of the match value
# For right container I have created jQuery tabs (tab1, tab2, tab3)
# The content of the right container in the tab will update according to the link in the left.
#Layout is given below

               ! tab1  ! tab2 ! tab3 !            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------               
!  434.4456    !  Show Default Match 1 Record                           !
!  434.4245    !  &  left hyperlink onclick show it's value record      !
!  434.4270    !  detail. I have design tab with JQuery                 !
!  434.2470    !                                                        !
!  434.4234    !                                                        !
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

==**Left container**(result.html)==

```
#I am looping through the queryset/list of values that was match with template for tag
#The template variable is given a hyperlink so after clicking it's detail information 
 will be shown on right container

<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a.id').click(function(){
        value = $ ('a.id').val();
        $('div#tab_content')empty().load('{%url index%}?query'= +value);
        });
    });

<div id="main">
     <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="1" bordercolor="#996600">
          <tr>
              <th>Match</th>
          </tr>     
               {% for section in sections %}
          <tr>
              <td><a href="#" id="{{%section.monoiso%}}">{{section.monoiso}}</a></td>
          </tr>
               {% endfor %}
       </table>
</div>
```

==**PROBLEMS**==

- I don't know how to get hyperlink value!
- jQuery ajax request on hyperlink (left container) is not working
- I am not sure about loading **index view** from **result.html** is correct
- I am sending data to server from the hyperlink with `<a href.... id="{{%section.monoiso%}}"`, how can I use same **id value** for querying in the **index view** and response in the result.html?
- How to render response in the right container?

Suggestions, comments and answer are appreciated.

Comment: There are [quite some](http://mitchfournier.com/2011/06/06/getting-started-with-ajax-in-django-a-simple-jquery-approach/) tutorials [available](http://webcloud.se/log/AJAX-in-Django-with-jQuery/) on this subject when you [search](http://www.google.nl/search?q=django+ajax+jquery) for it. What is the specific part you have issues with?

Comment: I have gone through google search till 10 page before asking here. The link you have provided are not unknown to me. If I had solved (comprehended) then wouldn't have trouble asking here!

Comment: I have list of link with associated value from queryset on the right column.  After clicking individual link I want to display it's detail information through generating new queryset on the right DIV column (tab separated). This is problem i have got !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some starting points. First, the view you call via Ajax does not necessarily have to return a json-object: the data can also be returned as a string using `django.http.HttpResponse` (or `render_to_response`, which boils down to the same thing). This means you can also return an entirely generated template as usual.

Assuming your posted view is found at `/index/(?<tab>\d+)/(?<match>\d+)/` (`tab` being the tab index, `match` being the match index), your javascript could look like this:

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");     // Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active");                // Add "active" class to this tab
    $(".tab_content").hide();                  // Hide all tab content

    // Construct the url based on the current index
    match_name = $("ul.match li").index($("ul.match li.active"));
    url = "/index/" + $("ul.tabs li").index($(this)) + "/" + match_name + "/";

    // Asynchronous ajax call to 'url'
    new $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: true,
        // The function below will be reached when the request has completed
        success: function(transport)
        {
            $(".tab_content").html(transport); // Put data in the div
            $(".tab_content").fadeIn();        // Fade in the active content
        }
    });
});
```

I didn't test this, but something along these lines should do. Note that for this to work with your current code, you view's `index` function needs to allow for a parameter. If you just want to test it with the same page for each tab, make the url look like this: `url = "/index/";` so that it'll most likely work right away.

Comment: I have updated my question precisely this time. Will go through your suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're exactly after, but I updated the answer to include the match index in the url.

Comment: I have populated template (2 columns), on the left I have template variable looping which give me match query with link. Further, I want to show match query link detail information on the right column on individual link click. The match value have relationship with various data model that's why wanted to show them in tabs. Sorry for not being clear enough! Really appreciated your help

Comment: Please explain what your _current_ problem is. As far as I can tell, the posted snippet will roughly do what you want (save for some names or id's). Do you have issues with calling the Django view? Or is the template rendered incorrectly? The ajax callback? Or the updating of the page itself? Feel free to update your question with any additional information you ran into while attempting to resolve things.

Comment: @ jro- I have given my best this time and updated question thoroughly. Can you please help me out?

Comment: @thchand: I created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qwYu9/58/) to give you some help on the client side. The `url` should of course be replaced by `{% url index %}`; the data you can get in the view with `request.POST.get('html')` (to use the fiddle as the example). The `html` name can be anything in your code, but for jsFiddle it is required to be like that. I hope this answers all your questions, but it is quite hard (a bit too localized perhaps) to make this a remote debugging session.

Comment: I want to query match_1, match_2, match_3 and display queryset variable instead!

Comment: Like I said, you'll have to replace the `url` to match the one matching your own implementation, for example change the line with "url" in the click handler for the tabs to `url: '/match/' + match + '/tab/' + tab + '/',`. This will create an url like `/match/1/tab/2/`. If you have a view defined as `myview(request, match_id, tab_id)` it will reach that (given the correct url handler). Whatever is returned from that view will be placed into the "Response placeholder" part shown in that fiddle.